# want to use $_POST['email'] to set receiver email in php mail function

Tags: php, mysql, forms, email

can anyone help me with this problem im having. what im trying to get to happen is when i submit a php form to my MySQL database that an email is sent at the same time but what i want to happen is that the the email is sent to the email address inputted on the form. sadly anything i have tried just isn't working here is what i have so  far:

Here is the form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="add_player_form" name="form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_player"/>
                    <h3>Add New Player</h3>
                    <label>First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
                    <br /><br />
                    <label>Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" />
                    <br /><br />
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" />
                    <br /><br />
                    <label>Position:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="position" />
                    <br /><br />
                    <label>Date Of Birth:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="dob" />
                    <br /><br />
                    <label>Country:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="country" />
                    <br /><br />
                    <label>City/Town:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city_town" />
                    <br /><br />
                    <label></label><input type="submit" value="ADD" onClick="randomString();" />
                    <br /><br />
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_type_id" value="2" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="team_id" value="<?php echo $teamId ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="password" value=""/>
                </form>
```

Here is the php code from index.php:

```
else if ($action == 'add_player') {
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $position = $_POST['position'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $city_town = $_POST['city_town'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $team_id = $_POST['team_id'];
    $user_type_id = $_POST['user_type_id'];
    add_player($last_name, $first_name, $dob, $position, $email, $country, $city_town, $password, $team_id, $user_type_id); //edit
    $team_manager = get_players();

    //$to = $_POST['email']; // this is the player's Email address
    $from = "teammanager0@outlook.com"; // this is the web app's Email address
    $subject = "Welcome to Team Manager";
    $message = "You have been added to a team on our web app TEAM MANAGER!" . "\n\n" . "In order to login to your team please use 
        the following details: " . "\n\n" . "Email: " . $email . "\n\n" . "Password: " . $password;
    //$message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $headers = "From:" . $from;

    mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);

    include('userPage.php');
}
```

and also my SMTP configuration:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.live.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = teammanager0@outlook.com
```

any help would be hugely appreciated and if you need more info please ask, cheers everyone !

Comment: Your code should work.  What exactly is your question?  Are you getting some error, or is it sending somewhere other than $_POST['email']?

Comment: In your code: First thing noticed, is that pieces are missing. Like the code starting from else if.. and the include at the bottom. Those should be removed, as they are irrelevant to the question or is they? Second thing is, that I cannot see any reference to mysql, or is the `add_player();` mysql function?

Comment: One of your functions is at fault. Tested this without them, and Email came in to, and from input.

Comment: Or possibly your SMTP configuration is wrong.  Are you sure you can relay mail through smtp.live.com without authenticating?

Comment: The email isn't being received is the problem Rob and Kalle i didnt include the code before the else if because its not relevant and yes the addplayer() is a mysql function from another file, sorry for any confusion

Comment: Fred could you tell me which functions are at fault? what did you change to make it work please? and Rob im not sure how i would go about authenticating it, i havent come across anything that mentioned it

Comment: Well, hopefully live.com locks down their SMTP server so that not just anyone can send mail through it.  I'm not sure how to authenticate either.  From your settings it looks like you're running this on Windows.  Is that your final production environment?  If not, and your production environment is linux, then you can just use sendmail and not worry about authenticating.

Comment: its not linux im afraid so maybe its the authentication although iv set an echo to test whether or not the message is actually sent and its coming back that it is being sent

Comment: So basically, the mysql function works? Also, you are not getting any PHP errors? Simply, the email doesn't reach you? Are you hosting in live.com, because why not use the SMTP of your local ISP?

Comment: yeah the email just isnt being received, i tried using my local ISP but it didnt work either.

Comment: I commented out these lines `add_player($last_name, $first_name, $dob, $position, $email, $country, $city_town, $password, $team_id, $user_type_id);` and `$team_manager = get_players();` and of course `include('userPage.php');` since I didn't have to use it. @user3246713 - And in order that I get notification in this thread, include the `@` symbol followed by my name.

Answer (score 1):

So, nobody is answering and probably I will get some downvotes. But your problem is not going to go away by itself, so lets start debugging!

First thing I noticed, was the the code is incomplete, so basically without it, we cannot confirm, that the problem isn't somewhere else. Since you said its not relevant, I deleted everything, that was commented out and / or we didn't have any reference at (like the mysql functions and etc.)

Since some of the code is missing, I don't know if your problem is there or not. But `else if ($action == 'add_player') {` at the start and `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_player"/>`, would suggest, that your missing the _POST action value. If this is the case, then add `$action = $_POST['action'];` in the head of the code. Or change the `$action` to `$_POST['action']`.

If the above idea doesn't work, then try my nerffed code:

```
<?

// Removed the first hidden input and merged it with submit button
if ($_POST['action'] == 'Add Player') {

    print 'Submit action was trigged, lets hope also the mails report is going to be good.<br />';

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $position = $_POST['position'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $city_town = $_POST['city_town'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $team_id = $_POST['team_id'];
    $user_type_id = $_POST['user_type_id'];

    $from = "TeamManager <teammanager0@outlook.com>"; // Made format different, to support the name
    $subject = "Welcome to Team Manager";
    $message = "You have been added to a team on our web app TEAM MANAGER!" . "\n\n" . "In order to login to your team please use 
        the following details: " . "\n\n" . "Email: " . $email . "\n\n" . "Password: " . $password;
    $headers = "From: " . $from; // added whitespace

    if (mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        print 'Email was sent by the PHP code, and the rest is up to the gods of the internet highway.<br />';
    }
}

print '<form action="" method="post">

    <h3>Add New Player</h3>
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />

    <br />
    <br />

    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" />

    <br />
    <br />

    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" />

    <br />
    <br />

    <label>Position:</label>
    <input type="text" name="position" />

    <br />
    <br />

    <label>Date Of Birth:</label>
    <input type="text" name="dob" />

    <br />
    <br />

    <label>Country:</label>
    <input type="text" name="country" />

    <br />
    <br />

    <label>City/Town:</label>
    <input type="text" name="city_town" />

    <br />
    <br />

    <label></label>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Add Player" onClick="randomString();" />

    <br />
    <br />

    <input type="hidden" name="user_type_id" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="team_id" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value=""/>

</form>';
```

This code as you can see is fairly debugged and also the hidden input has been replaced to submit-trigger. So try it out, and let us know what is the result, do you see the two notices?

---

**EDIT:** So, the above code worked fine in my server. Meaning, that if the stuff, that I nerffed out from your code, isn't the problem (and we cannot verify that without seeing it) then your code isn't the problem. Possible other problems are:

- Your ISP is blocking your outgoing emails (or your servers config. is wrong)
- Your SMTP settings and wrong
- Your testing e-mail service is considering your test-emails as spam. My ISP once official said, that too short and suspicious looking e-mails get treated as spam. So try testing it with different e-mail services and with more content-text

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was, i wasn't configuring the correct php file for my smpt settings, thanks to everyone for responding to my question, very much appreciated !